# For this while loop I get to input a number but when I enter a number, the program does not show any output and keeps running?

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

**To print sum of n natural numbers**

I get the output as enter a number after I enter a number I dont get the sum and the program does not end.

The code is as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i,n,s;
    i=1;s=0;
    printf("Enter a number:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    while(i<=n); //loop runs n times
    {
        s=s+i; 
        i++;
    }
    printf("%d",s);
}
```

Edit: After saving the code, its giving desired output. There's absolutely no problem with the code although could not find out what happened earlier.

Not deleting this post for anyone with similar problem, just try to save your source code file and then run it.

Comment: i think you forgot return 0

Comment: @Rishi_jha Try to write printf("%d\n",s);

Comment: @LiorTabachnik That is entirely unnecessary.

Comment: Add `printf("n=%d i=%d s=%d\n", n, i, s);` inside the loop. That should _rapidly_ hint you about where you are going wrong...

Comment: Infinite loop `while(i<=n); `